# Reason for caching in LAMP application

Tags: mysql, caching, lamp

My application runs on the LAMP platform.

One database table has been updated to modify the dropdown list options for one of the select input type in a web page.

But when I test the webpage the changes are reflected. I check the application connecting to customer VPN. When the customer check the same thing it still shows the old content.

Changes made to solve the issue are as follows -

```
1.  Cleared the browser cache
2.  Made sure there is no caching enabled in Apache
3.  Changed the file creation datetime so that it picks the new file for execution and DB query
4.  Flushed MySQL query cache
5.  Removed Linux page cache
```

But customer is not able to see the changes made. And still sees the old content.

Can anyone guess what could be the reason for caching? Please help.

Comment: Browser cache is completely cleared which must take the new content from the server I believe.

Comment: Are you sure that you and your customer are connecting to the same server?  Not a case of a dev/QA server vs. a production server?

Comment: We have only one UAT server and we are connecting to the same server.